# Trouble with simple makefile in C

Tags: makefile

I am somewhat of a beginner in C and have a project due where I need to include a makefile to compile my single file program that uses pthreads and semaphores. My makefile looks like:

```
# Makefile for pizza program 
pizza: pizza.o
    gcc -lrt -lpthread -g -o pizza pizza.o

pizza.o: pizza.c
    gcc -lrt -lpthread -g -c pizza.o pizza.c
```

and I keep getting:

`make: Nothing to be done for 'Makefile'.`

I have done several makefiles before and have never gotten this message. I've tried different semantics in the makefile and have only gotten this same message. And yes, the command is tabbed after the target and dependency line.

Using gcc on tcsh. I have read other makefile posts on SO but I wasn't able to use any of the answers to figure it out for my case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you running `make Makefile` instead of just `make`? Also `tcsh` is apparently not a good (or usable) choice of shell for makefile usage (though this makefile doesn't actually seem to use `tcsh` for its rule execution).

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, "make Makefile" is my command

Comment: That is telling make to try to run the target for `Makefile`... which doesn't exist so make can't do anything. You mean `make` to run the default target or `make pizza` to run the `pizza` target.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ok, I will try that. I thought in the past I always used "make makefile" or "make Makefile".

Comment: You might have used `make -f Makefile` since `-f` is "use this file as the makefile".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `make` are the targets to be built.

You are running `make Makefile` which is telling `make` to try to build the `Makefile` target.

There is no such target in your makefile, make has no built-in rule that applies to that target and the file exists (and is assumed to be up-to-date) which is what that message is telling you.

To run the default target (by default the first target listed) you can just run `make` (assuming you are using a default name like `Makefile` for your makefile).

You can also use the `-f` argument to `make` to select an alternate makefile name.

So `make -f Makefile` will in this case (since `Makefile` is a default searched name) do the same thing as `make`.